# Negative Version of given regex needed (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Again and again Regex...
Can please someone show me how to got the negative lookahead working with the given regex here: https://regex101.com/r/kS6wUh/1

The Regex looks like this: `^\b[A-Z]+|_+?[A-Z]+`

Target would be to check if a given string contains only Characters A-Z or _

```
Invalid_TEXT (invalid)
all_in_small_invalid (invalid)
INVALID-DASH (invalid)
VALID_KEY (valid)
ANOTHER_VALID_KEY (valid)
 (empty --> invalid)
```

The regex should match on invalid my current returns the valid matches.

I have no clue where to add `(?!...)` in my current version because all options I've tried ended up either by getting a regex error or counting everything. I think my regex has not the correct structure for a negative lookahead.

Comment: Besides the answer below of checking for characters that not in the set, to do what you originally intended you can use `^[A-Z_]+$`  Need to set line start `^` and end `$` so that it considers the whole string and not return partial matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to test if one or more characters in the string are *not* of the set `[A-Z_]`, which is done by inserting a caret. So `[^A-Z_]`. Demo

```js
const strs = `Invalid_TEXT
all_in_small_invalid
INVALID-DASH
VALID_KEY
ANOTHER_VALID_KEY
 (empty)`.split(`\n`);
 
strs.forEach(str => console.log(str, /[^A-Z_]/.test(str) ? `Not ok` : `OK`));
```